# Markdown to RST with pandoc, how to convert :any:`foo_bar`

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext

Trying to convert the following from markdown to RST using pandoc:

Markdown:

`` :any:`foo_bar` ``

Converts to:

``` :any:``foo_bar`` ```

But I would like the following:

`` :any:`foo_bar` ``

Any ideas? String replacement of ``` `` ``` to `` ` `` is painful as it is within a table which means adding 2 spaces for every replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown uses single backticks for code spans, RST double backticks. So the conversion is correct.

```
some text `foo_bar`
```

is translated to

```
some text ``foo_bar``
```

Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish but note that Pandoc Markdown doesn't (as of yet) support directives or similar constructs like you seem to imply with `:foo:`.

To write RST directives inside your markdown, you should probably use a code block with a custom class like:

````
``` {.rst-mydirective}
foo bar
```
````

then write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to replace the code block with the text you need.

Comment: Yes I am aware that markdown does not support directives, but I am trying to "cheat" and write in markdown which is easier and then pandoc it to rst, especially since rst is so tedious with tables. Hence I need a "literal" translation of that. But yes, I don't see it happening.